# MediaPlayer playing in background throws unexpected end of stream

Tags: android, service, media-player

We are developing an app that plays podcasts, we are using services and the media player to play the files that are in the server, in some Marshmallow devices we are encountering this error (Motorola g4):

```
W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 22575768 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
```

But it only happens when the app is killed and the service starts to run, when the app is in foreground it works well, we have noticed that the buffering is working well, but when the app is killed it cannot buffer more, it recahes a limit and then it throws that error... In other devices the buffering is working well.

Here is the chunk of the code that prepares the media player.

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "audio/mp3");
headers.put("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
headers.put("Status", "206");

mp = new MediaPlayer();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(songPath); 

mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri, headers);
mp.prepareAsync();
```

The headers were added because a post we saw, but it has the same result as if it doesn't have it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Playing audio in background is a bit more complex than that. If you're just using a `MediaPlayer`, then that component's container (i.e. `Activity`) or the open http connection are probably being destroyed when Android decides to release resources. This can happen as soon as you switch to another app, or when the device (some other app) is using too many resources, or when the operating system decides it's a good time to do it.

However, `MediaPlayer` is just one part of the background audio playing.
I'd advice you to take a look at the oficial guide on how to build an Audio app. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html

I also found a well-explained step-by-step tutorial that can also help
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030

Comment: Yep, it's done as the tutorial there, it works marvelous in other devices, when the song finishes the next song starts ok (it keeps perfectly the urls and the media player) ... I think is something with the stream and the GC... The length of each piece of song is about 30 minutes or more

Comment: Have you acquired a wifi lock so that the wifi stays on when the device screen is off?

Comment: It has a receiver to detect the internet connection change :/ and it also happens when the user is in other apps...Right now I am testing while navigating on Twitter app and only in Andorid 6 is happening the error. :/ In other phones it works pretty well.